# How to write a FileDescriptor to a new file (Android)

Tags: android, file, descriptor

I have a FileDescriptor open (credits to Andrew) in Android Studio and i want to write it to a new file (copy), how can i do that?

Comment: so you want to copy the file, right?

Comment: Yes sir, to getExternalFilesDir() path

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Files.copy](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) method the following way:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(descriptor);
Path            path  = Paths.get(outDirectoryName, outFileName);

Files.copy(input, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
input.close();
```