# Scoped Storage - How to get one app to share text file to another app

Tags: android, file-io, text-files, scoped-storage

We have two apps that share data between each other.  App A creates a text file with parameters to be read by App B. Then App B reads the text file created by App A with the parameters to be used for certain functionality.

I was wondering, is there any way this can be accomplished using scoped storage? I couldn't find any solution. I am not sure if this is a valid use case for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

EDIT: Here is my FileProvider code from App A:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
String filename = ".bisym";
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "bisym/" + filename;
File file = new File(fullPath);
Uri uriToText = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.octal.provider2", file);
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToText);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
           
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

How would I parse this file from App B? In App B I would also like to copy this file into its own private app directory.

Comment: There are several posibilities. App A can for instance start app B and put a FileProvider uri in the used intent so App B can read the file.

Answer (score 0):

save text file in public directory Like Download , Document

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
String filename = ".bisym";
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "bisym/" + filename;

File file = new File(fullPath);
Uri uriToText = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.octal.provider2", file);
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToText);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
           
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | 
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Add Manifest

```
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.yoursecondapp" />
         
</queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is using FileProvider, but you need to share your directory in order to generate a temporary content URI for the file.

The steps you need to follow are explained in detail here : https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing

Comment: So, with a FileDescriptor, how would I copy it to App B's app-specific directory? There seems to be zero information about this anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743025/how-to-write-a-filedescriptor-to-a-new-file-android

Comment: It's explained on the link I gave above, on lessons 'Requesting a shared file' and 'Retrieving file information'. But you need to share your file before.